# Access resource from the same folder

Tags: python, python-3.6

My Python 3.6 app has the following structure:

```
app/
|__ utility.py
|__ resource.txt
|__ notebooks/
    |__ sandbox.ipynb
```

In `utility.py`, I have a function that reads the resource file:

```
# utility.py
def do_something():
    with open('resource.txt') as f:
        content = f.read()
```

All is well and good.

The problem is when I import utility in `sandbox.ipynb`, the function fails because it couldn't find the `resource.txt` file under the `notebooks` folder:

```
# sandbox.ipynb
import sys
if '..' not in sys.path
    sys.path.append('..')

from utility import do_something # ok
do_something() # resource.txt not found
```

What is the Pythonic way to make `do_something` always read from the `resource.txt` file that is located in the same folder as `utility.py`? A senior developer at my company discouraged the use of `__file__` because it may point to the wrong location for a zip package. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the directory of the file that's being executed like this:

```py
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
resource_filepath = os.path.join(dir_path, 'resource.txt')

def do_something():
    with open(resource_filepath) as f:
        content = f.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The senior dev said `__file__` will not work if the package is a zip file. In that case, `__file__` will point to the zip file rather than the absolute path of `utility.py`. What do you think about that?

Comment: So, is your package in zip archive or not? If it's not then `__file__` is what you need.
If it's in a zip file then it's a whole different approach, you can't read a file ('resource.txt') from zip archive using `open` method, you'd need to use [`zipfile` utils](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)

Comment: I'm taking the issue to the team today. Let's see what everyone has to say. Thanks for the answer though